# Pandas: count number of duplicate rows using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with duplicate rows

```py
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({'n': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'v': [1,2,1]})
>>> d
   n  v
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  1
```

I would like to understand how to use `.groupby()` method specifically so that I can add a new column to the dataframe which shows count of rows which are identical to the current one.

```
>>> dd = d.groupby(by=['n','v'], as_index=False)  # Use all columns to find groups of identical rows
>>> for k,v in dd:
...      print(k, "\n", v, "\n")  # Check what we found
... 
('a', 1) 
    n  v
0  a  1
2  a  1 

('a', 2) 
    n  v
1  a  2
```

When I'm trying to do `dd.count()` on resulting `DataFrameGroupBy` object I get `IndexError: list index out of range`. This seems to happen because all columns are used in grouping operation and there's no other column to use for counting. Similarly `dd.agg({'n', 'count'})` fails with `ValueError: no results`.

I could use `.apply()` to achieve something that looks like result.

```py
>>> dd.apply(lambda x: x.assign(freq=len(x)))
     n  v  freq
0 0  a  1     2
  2  a  1     2
1 1  a  2     1
```

However this has two issues: 1) something happens to the index so that it is hard to map this back to the original index, 2) this does not seem idiomatic Pandas and manuals [discourage](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) using `.apply()` as it could be slow.

Is there more idiomatic way to count duplicate rows when using `.groupby()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for aggregate output with counter:

```
d = d.groupby(by=['n','v']).size().reset_index(name='c')
print (d)
   n  v  c
0  a  1  2
1  a  2  1
```

Your solution working if specify some column name after `groupby`, because no another columns `n`, `v` in input `DataFrame`:

```
d = d.groupby(by=['n','v'])['n'].count().reset_index(name='c')

print (d)
   n  v  c
0  a  1  2
1  a  2  1
```

What is also necessary if need new column with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) - new column is filled by aggregate values:

```
d['c'] = d.groupby(by=['n','v'])['n'].transform('size')
print (d)
   n  v  c
0  a  1  2
1  a  2  1
2  a  1  2
```